# Is there a tool like getfacl/setfacl for users/groups?

Tags: linux, backup, file-permissions

I am trying to backup a directory to cloud storage, but since most solutions do not natively support specifying the user/group of a file I would like to save the user/group to a file and backup that file so that they can be restored if/when the backup is needed.

[`getfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl)/[`setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) can be used for this for rwx permissions ([as described here](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/1202#issuecomment-283971515)) but is there a similar tool for users/groups?

Comment: Utterly no idea why this question was downvoted. It‘s valid and addresses a very real world issue of non-native (aka: “cloud”) storage systems not storing some basic/necessary metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the resources you linked to.

From [here](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/1202#issuecomment-283971515):

> ```
> getfacl -R / >permissions.facl
> setfacl --restore=permissions.facl
> ```

(In your case it will be `/some/dir` instead of `/`).

And then [`man 1 setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) [emphasis mine]:

> `--restore=file`
>   Restore a permission backup created by `getfacl -R` or similar. All permissions of a complete directory subtree are restored using this mechanism. **If the input contains owner comments or group comments, `setfacl` attempts to restore the owner and owning group.** […]

Note you need [`CAP_CHOWN` capability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229553/108618) to change ownership. This applies to any method.

---

If you need to restore *only* users+groups (without touching ACLs) from `permissions.facl`, there are at least two options:

1. Parse the file and dynamically build a script containing many `chmod` lines. I won't build a parser here. Note file names (i.e. `# file:` entries) may contain translated troublesome/unprintable characters and you need to translate them back.
2. Possible workaround (untested!):

   - save current metadata with `getfacl -R` to `current.facl`;
   - remove all owner comments and group comments from `current.facl`;
   - restore metadata from `permissions.facl`;
   - restore metadata from `current.facl`.

   Restoring from `current.facl` will revert everything that restoring from `permissions.facl` did, except users+groups. In the end only users+groups will depend on `permissions.facl`.

Comment: Ah I assumed the comments were just comments - thanks